# Mat::push_back leads to memory leak in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

I tried to extract SIFT features of about 8000 images and put them into one `Mat`.

Below is my code:

```
Mat feature, im, SIFTFeatures;
char imgFile[50];
SiftFeatureDetector detector;
SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;

for (int view = 0; view < imageNum; view++)
{
    sprintf(imgFile, "image_%04d.jpg", view+1);
    im = imread(imgFile);

    vector<KeyPoint> tmpKey;
    detector.detect(im, tmpKey);
    if (tmpKey.size() == 0){
        printf("%d\t%d no keypoints\n", obj, view);
        continue;
    }
    extractor.compute(im, tmpKey, feature);
    SIFTFeatures.push_back(feature);

    feature.release();
    im.release();
}
```

Then an error occurred saying that insufficient memory when allocating about 800MB memory. But my laptop has 16GB memory so I think memory leak happened somewhere.

And the most likely one is `SIFTFeatures.push_back(feature);`

But I don't know why and how to avoid this error.

The reason I use `SIFTFeature` is that I need to add all features to a `BOWKMeansTrainer` to extract BOW features.

Comment: the Mat::Allocator works quite similar like a std::vector : whenever there's not enough space to push_back a new element, it *doubles* its capacity. later it will find out, that it allocated far too much, and will throw away a lot of that again, but for a short moment, you will see sharp 'spikes', and yes, eventually run out of memory, if you're already close to the limit.

Comment: do you really need a `Mat SIFTFeatures` there ? a `vector<Mat>` would probably avoid the problem

Comment: Cause I need to add all features to a `BOWKMeansTrainer trainer(500)`. I also tried `trainer.add(feature)` for each image but also get an insufficient memory error.

Comment: Have you ever tried to create your Mat's     feature and im inside the for loop? Are you limiting the number of features per image? Have you tried to use a smaller set  of images to train?